# How to summarize by an unknown number of columns?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to create summaries for the results of a certain type of task across multiple geographic regions. I currently have the following dummy query:

```
datatable(env_cloud_location : string, result : string )[
    "East Asia", "Passed",
    "East Asia", "Failed",
    "East Asia", "Error",
    "East US", "Passed",
    "East US", "Error",
    "East US", "Passed",
    "North Europe", "Failed",
    "North Europe", "Error",
    "North Europe", "Error",
]
| summarize 
    eastAsia = countif(env_cloud_location  == "East Asia"),
    eastUS = countif(env_cloud_location  == "East US"),
    northEurope = countif(env_cloud_location == "North Europe")
    by result
```

Now, I suppose I don't know all the possible values of "env_cloud_location" and there in fact are anywhere from 5 to 12, how can I summarize such that each of these locations, however many there are, gets their own column? Expected output in the format:

| result | eastAsia | eastUS | northEurope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Passed | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Failed | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Error | 1 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) question

```
datatable(env_cloud_location : string, result : string )[
    "East Asia", "Passed",
    "East Asia", "Failed",
    "East Asia", "Error",
    "East US", "Passed",
    "East US", "Error",
    "East US", "Passed",
    "North Europe", "Failed",
    "North Europe", "Error",
    "North Europe", "Error",
]
| evaluate pivot(env_cloud_location)
```

| result | East Asia | East US | North Europe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Passed | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| Failed | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Error | 1 | 1 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/dumarkovadx.westeurope.dev/databases/mydb?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA43QwQrCMAwG4Ptg7xB6ctAn8OZhHkUQT0NGXIMWSjPStCcf3oEgTFYwueUjPyEOdel7oB3FMk6BsxsDT6ieI%20whqfj4sCCUctDvALqhbWAp02NSOCSPxoI5Y0rkjN2yI/pQs16EZU3XSy3wI/%20unFj0CX0WnmnjjF9ex1b11jYvoIIhoxLMvrBu/K97A5ibrW5dAQAA)

Comment: I always forget that Pivot tables exist. Thanks for reminding me.